# Undefined status flag values in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, flags, x86-16

I found list of intel 8086 commands and how every instruction affects flags (http://www.gabrielececchetti.it/Teaching/CalcolatoriElettronici/Docs/i8086_instruction_set.pdf).

The problem is that I have no idea what happens, if flag for certain instruction is undefined (marked as ?).

For example, if we set auxiliary flag as 1, and run `XOR BX, A3BA`, where `BX` is `04B7`, auxiliary flag becomes zero after instruction execution. In the document, we can see that `XOR` marks auxiliary flag as undefined. So how to determine how flags change if they are undefined?

Comment: Undefined means that the value of the flag can be anything. Zero is a valid value of "anything".

Comment: @RaymondChen so it is not a mistake to say that after this command, auxiliary flag can be either 1 or 0 (random)?

Comment: That is what "undefined" means. The specification provides no definition. Therefore any behavior is legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flags are set based on the result of each instruction. Some flags (like the A flag) may not have any meaning for some instructions. It is meaningless to talk about a 4-bit carry (which is what the A flag indicates) when you're performing an instruction that doesn't involve 4-bit arithmetic.

Concern yourself with the flags that have meaning for the instruction you're executing and ignore the rest.